# How can I pass Pointer Matrix to Function in C?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I tried what is described in these links:

[How can I pass character pointer reference to function and get affected value back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991194/how-can-i-pass-character-pointer-reference-to-function-and-get-affected-value-ba)

[Passing pointers (matrix) to a function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422813/passing-pointers-matrix-to-a-function-in-c)

[Passing an array as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c)

but I can't. Dimension of my array is 3 and I initialized it like this:

char* trips[N][2] = {{"ANKARA", "10:00"}, {"BURSA", "11:00"}, {"IZMIR", "12:00"}, {"ISTANBUL", "13:00"}, {"ANTALYA", "14:00"}}
so how can I pass this matrix into function?

My code is here and it doesn't sort or effect my array.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

typedef enum {
  SortByCity,
  SortByHour
 }SortType;

void merge(char**, int, int, int, SortType);
void mergeSort(char**, int, int, SortType);
void mergeSortByHour(char**, int, int, SortType);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
 int i;
 
 char* trips[N][2] = {{"ANKARA", "10:00"}, {"BURSA", "11:00"}, {"IZMIR", "12:00"}, {"ISTANBUL", "13:00"}, {"ANTALYA", "14:00"}, {"ANKARA", "11:00"}, {"ISTANBUL", "13:00"}, {"ANKARA", "11:30"}, {"BURSA", "21:00"} , {"BURSA", "13:00"}};
 mergeSort(**trips, 0, N-1, SortByCity);
 
 for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
  printf("%-10s %s\n", trips[i][0],  trips[i][1]);
 }
 return 0;
}


void merge(char** T, int L, int M, int H, SortType S){
 
 int i, j, k;
    int N1 = M - L + 1;
    int N2 = H - M;
    
    char* LA[N1][2], RA[N2][2];
    
    for (i = 0; i < N1; i++){
     LA[i][S] = T[L+i][S];
     LA[i][1-S] = T[L+i][1-S];
 }
    for (j = 0; j < N2; j++){
     RA[j][S] = T[L+j][S];
     RA[j][1-S] = T[L+j][1-S];
 }
        
        
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = L;
        
    while (i < N1 && j < N2)
    {
        if (strcmp(LA[i][S], RA[j][S]))
        {
            T[k][S] = RA[j][S];
            T[k][1-S] = RA[j][1-S];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            T[k][S] = LA[i][S];
            T[k][1-S] = LA[i][1-S];
            i++;
        }
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(char** T, int L, int H, SortType S){
 
 if(L < H)
  return;
  
 int M = (L + H) / 2;
 mergeSort(T, L, M, S);
 mergeSort(T, M+1, H, S);
 merge(T, L, M, H, S);
  
}
```

Please dont mark my question as duplicate because I dont understand the solutions explained in the site and can't solve my problem.

Comment: Stop merge sorting and start playing with a variable and a function until you can pass it correctly.

Comment: I'm not answering since I'm not familiar with this area of C enough, but this is what I came up with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43b1f52fa50d17f1. I did this with the help of method 2 here: http://www.firmcodes.com/pass-2d-array-parameter-c-2/. 2d arrays are just one contiguous block in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory

Comment: @MillieSmith tried it all day but I failed again and again.

Comment: I understand. C can be unforgiving. That code I gave above should get you moving again.

Comment: Methinks first link solved passing problem but still mergeSort function does not effect my array. The compiler gives me this error: [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast for this line of code :LA[i][S] = T[L+i][S];

Comment: Yeah. Look at the type of the parameter and imagine what happens when you index into it twice. Then look at my code and see that I don't do that. Then look at the last link I linked above which states that memory is contiguous for 2d arrays.

Comment: These short variable names are killing me, man. You're gonna have a hard time after you've slept too.

Comment: `void merge(char**, int, int, int, SortType);` --> `void merge(char*[][2], int, int, int, SortType);` ... `mergeSort(trips, 0, N-1, SortByCity);`

Comment: You've also run into another fun bug in C where `RA` is declared as a `char[][]` instead of a `char*[][]` because the star is only associated with the first declaration on that line.

Comment: `char* LA[N1][2], RA[N2][2];` --> `char *LA[N1][2], *RA[N2][2];`

Comment: thx bros. u re genius and funny boys but function still dont effect my array

Comment: Should I use strcpy() function to assign R arrays element to T?

Comment: `RA[j][S] = T[L+j][S];` : `L+j` is wrong. and `while (i < N1 && j < N2)` : It is not enough to process only in the case of `i < N1 && j < N2`.

Comment: @JonahThunderbolt Look at here: [How to pass a multidimensional C array to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447631/2913477)

Comment: `if(L < H)` --> `if(L >= H)`, `if (strcmp(LA[i][S], RA[j][S]))` --> `if (strcmp(LA[i][S], RA[j][S]) > 0)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah epic fail L<H